Safe to publish Oauth2 Client IDs with localhost redirects?
I cannot seem to find a definitive answer on this. I have found various related questions, but none of them answer this question completely.
I want to distribute a desktop application that uses an Oauth2 flow (using authorization code flow with PKCE) to sign the user into a third party service. Since it is a desktop application, the redirect URL must run on localhost in order to capture the authorization code.
Is it safe to distribute the application with the client ID essentially hard coded into the source code?
Since the redirect URL is to localhost, it seems to me that anyone could re-use my Client ID for their own malicious app that uses a localhost redirect. This is a different story for a non-localhost redirect since in that case, I would control an https guarded domain, and the third party service would only redirect to that approved domain. In this case, I need to add localhost as an approved domain in the third party service.
To run through an example attack, let's say an attacker wants to get a user's token for the service I am using in my app. They could distribute their own malicious version of my app (using my Client ID). A user that mistakenly installs and uses the malicious app would start the auth flow (and would even see my application's name during the sign-in process). Then on the redirect, the malicious app can use the auth code to obtain a token and exfiltrate it elsewhere.
In other answers people have mentioned PKCE as guarding against this, but I don't see how that would do anything to prevent this attack. The malicious app could easily implement PKCE (and state/CSRF checking as well) - PKCE only ensures that the redirect was initiated by the same person (which in this case, it would be).
I feel like I must be missing something here. Is there a way to make distributing the Client ID safe for apps that use a localhost redirect? And if not, how can I implement an Oauth2 flow that doesn't require users to create their own Client IDs?
